# Plasma crashes when I switch applications using taskbar

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

I have KUbuntu 16.04 with all the latest updates.

Everytime I switch application using taskbar, Plasma crashes with a segmentation fault.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fault with the tool tip generation in Plasma.

Disabling Tooltips in Taskbar settings fixed the problem.